# How do I delete mysql records from 2 tables, but if no records in 2nd table still delete from 1st table?

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

This works when a job has files. It deletes the file records from files table and job records from jobs table, however, if job has no files, nothing happens. I want it to still delete the job record from the jobs table if the job doesn't have files associated with it.

```
DELETE jobs, files FROM jobs INNER JOIN files WHERE jobs.id = $id AND files.jobid = jobs.id
```

I tried like the following but it didn't work:

```
DELETE jobs, files FROM jobs INNER JOIN files WHERE jobs.id = $id OR files.jobid = jobs.id
```

Also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
DELETE jobs, files FROM jobs INNER JOIN files on jobs.id = files.jobid WHERE jobs.id = $id
```

EDIT:

here is what worked.  it's based from the answer marked as correct below, but slightly different.

```
DELETE jobs, files FROM jobs LEFT JOIN files ON files.jobid = jobs.id WHERE jobs.id = $id
```

it didn't like that short code or whatever that is (when people say files f or jobs j then later they say f.jobid or j.id).  and it may not have liked the stars/asterisks when first declaring the tables (not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using a `LEFT JOIN` would solve your problem:

```sql
DELETE j.*, f.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN files f
    ON f.jobid = j.id
WHERE j.id = $id
```

Comment: @leoarce Well, does the table exist? You've given the same table names in your question.